# Lambdaj or apache predicate for filtering and modifying list item

Tags: java, apache-commons, spring-batch, lambdaj

I am working on a data loader, implemented using Spring Batch i.e. reading multiple flat files, processing and writing the list of pojo at commit interval of 1000  to database.
Each line read from file is converted to a pojo object containing property that needs to be set on the outcome of processing.

I have a lookup table that contains three columns with 180 rows. I keep each column values in a separate lists and iterate the list in a predicate to match with the each POJO item property.if a match is found in all the lists , then a property will be set.The following is the predicates i use,

```
public class LogicProcessor<I, O> implements ItemProcessor<I, O> {

    private Map[] params ;

    public void setParams( Map[] params )
    {
        this.params = params;
    }

    public O process(I item) throws Exception 
    {
        System.out.println(params  );

        List container      =  (List) params[1].get("SRVC");
        final List callInd      =  (List) container.get(0);
        final List totaltype        =  (List) container.get(1);
        final List servicetype  =   (List) container.get(2);

        Predicate<I> callIndipredicate = new Predicate<I>() {
            public boolean apply(I input) 
            {
                boolean flag=false;
                for (int i=0;i<callInd.size();i++)
                {
                    if ( "*".equals(callInd.get(i)))
                    {
                        flag= true;
                        break;
                    } else
                    {
                        try 
                        {
                            if (BeanUtils.getProperty(input,"CALLINDICATOR").equals(callInd.get(i)))
                            {
                                flag = true;
                                break;
                            } else
                            {
                                flag= false;
                                break;
                            }
                        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                }
                return flag;
            }
        };

        Predicate<I> totaltyppredicate = new Predicate<I>() {
            public boolean apply(I input) 
            {
                boolean flag=false;
                for (int i=0;i<totaltype.size();i++)
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        if (BeanUtils.getProperty(input,"TOTALTYPE").equals(totaltype.get(i)))
                        {
                            flag = true;
                            break;
                        } else
                        {
                            flag= false;
                            break;
                        }
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return flag; 
            }
        };

        Predicate<I>srvctypepredicate = new Predicate<I>() {
            public boolean apply(I input) 
            {
                boolean flag=false;
                for (int i=0;i<servicetype.size();i++)
                {
                    try 
                    {
                        if (BeanUtils.getProperty(input,"SERVICETYPE").equals(servicetype.get(i)))
                        {
                            flag = true;
                            break;
                        } else
                        {
                            flag= false;
                            break;
                        }
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return flag;                
            }
        };

        Predicate<I> isFound = Predicates.and(callIndipredicate,totaltyppredicate,srvctypepredicate);
        int preorPost=  Iterables.indexOf(Arrays.asList(item), isFound) ;
        System.out.println(preorPost);
        if (preorPost >=0)
        {
            BeanUtils.setProperty(item, "PREPOST", '0');
        } else
        {
            BeanUtils.setProperty(item, "PREPOST", 'X');
        }
        return (O) item;
    }

}
```

Is there a better way to filter the items and modify using  guava.

Comment: @dave my question was how do it in lambdaj

Comment: @SureshSakaDeadProgrammer: I think Dave was pointing out that you didn't provide any code, so we don't know what the result should be "better than."

Comment: @stripling: as i was posting  from iphone , i was not able to add code here.

Comment: Using hashset to find the item Is faster instead of loopin thru list.thanks stripling and dave for the time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Guava:* Use [Iterables.find](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#find%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Predicate%29) with a [Predicate](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Predicate.html) that does the DB lookup. Apply [transform](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#transform%28java.lang.Iterable,%20com.google.common.base.Function%29) to the result with a [Function](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html).

*Commons:* Use a [FilterListIterator](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/iterators/FilterListIterator.html) (or `FilterIterator`) combined with a [Predicate](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/Predicate.html), then a [TransformIterator](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/iterators/TransformIterator.html) with a [Transformer](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/Transformer.html).

Don't know about LambdaJ.